# Readystate is always 0

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, soap, cordova

I am working on phonegap app. I need to validate user through .net webservice. I am using ajax to validate and parsing it through javascript.but i am stuck at readystate as it always return *zero*. I tried many things from available solutions I found in net but I don't get it right.

Here is my Javascript:

```
username = 'ksl';
password = 'ksl';
var soapMessage = 
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
        <soap:Body> \
        <CheckLogin xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> \
        <UserName>' + username + '</UserName> \
        <Password>' + password + '</Password> \
        </CheckLogin> \
        </soap:Body> \
        </soap:Envelope>';

        $.ajax({
            url: validationURL,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapMessage,
            success: validate,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            error: function(xhr,status,error)
            {
            alert("state is:" + xhr.readyState);
            }
        }); 

        return false;
```

and here is my webservice response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckLoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CheckLoginResult>string</CheckLoginResult>
    </CheckLoginResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

any response will be helpful

Comment: Is this a cross domain request?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance related to javascript and ajax..but here i m using phonegap in which m using javascript and ajax. webservice is from .net..is it cross domain??

Comment: I have no experience with phonegap, but in normal web browsers you're not allowed to send ajax requests to a different host - that's the first thing that came to my mind, because you often see a request die in readystate 0 because of this crossdomain policy.

Comment: ok..i got it..no its not cross domain..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok..I found the problems::

1) there was space after  `</soap:Body> \`  so I removed that.

2) I made some changes in html and it works fine..

Thanks for having look at my problems..